# How to Add values in a table together using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, numbers, addition

I have an HTML table with number values. What I need to do is to get all these values and add them together using jQuery.

Any ideas?

---

Example table:

http://pastie.org/998759

Comment: It's just a basic table with numbers in each row.

Comment: It works now.  However, in the future, you should put the code directly in your question by clicking the Format Code button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.each`:

```
var sum = 0;

$('table td').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you some pseudo-code of how I would do it (mainly because I can't be stuffed writing the whole thing).

1. Create an object/array/variables to store the totals.
2. jQuery select the table
3. Use `.each()` to loop through each `tr`.
4. Loop each `td` and add the value to the relevant total.
5. Once all of the `tr` have been looped through, do whatever you want :)

Hope this helps you out :)

EDIT: I was writing the code as if you wanted to total each column, rather than all cells into a single total.

Answer (score 1):

It's already been answered. So just as a fun exercise:

```
// Give all arrays the power of summation    
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
    for( var i=0,sum=0;i<this.length;sum+=this[i++] );
    return sum;
}

// Use map for kicks
$(document).ready( function(){
    var result = $('table#mytable tr td').map( function(){
        return parseFloat( $(this).text() );
    }).get().sum();
});
```