# How to get value of td elemets on JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with numbers tht needs to be summarize. 
Example:

```
<td class="mcost_el.entry[0]">93,08</td>
<td class="mcost_el.entry[1]">544,33</td>
```

How get all values of td elements with class `mcost_el.entry[]` and summarize it?

For inputs i'm use `$('#d1').attr("value");`. Is suitable for this task? (by adding value="" for td)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I get, parse and sum all the tds' of a table with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018713/how-do-i-get-parse-and-sum-all-the-tds-of-a-table-with-jquery) and [How to Add values in a table together using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011157/how-to-add-values-in-a-table-together-using-jquery) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+sum+table+values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.text()` rather than what you have suggested.

Update your HTML to

```
<td class="mcost_el">93,08</td>
<td class="mcost_el">544,33</td>
```

Add in javascript for

```
var _total = 0;

$(function(){
    $('.mcost_el').each(function(){
         _total += parseFloat($(this).text()); // will give you the value.
    });
});
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/tqH4y/

Also, rather than using `.attr("value")` in the future, you can just use `.val()`

Comment: *you can just use `.val()`*, but not on `td` elements ;)

Comment: +1 for the full solution and the `parseFloat` but I'm not sure `.mcost_el` will select the td in the OP's example

Comment: @JMax, yeah i changed the class as i am guessing it was in that format to try and solve the problem originally and that it might not be needed with this solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var tdtotal = 0;
$("td[class^='mcost_el.entry[']").each(function() {
    tdtotal += parseInt($(this).text().replace(",","")); 
})
alert(tdtotal);
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/vnXCr/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure i'm answering correctly here, its unclear if you are seeking a way to get text from a TD element, or wether your having trouble targetting all td's with a certain class (selector issues)

`.attr("value")`  or better  `.val()`  is for input fields

if you want to get text from a TD element, you should be using:

```
$('td').text();
```